expo-image-picker too long base64 string
i have next code to pick image from user's gallery
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

i send base64 to my server but this string is unbelievable long, i've tried to set less quality - 0.7 and i got 10x less string but still to long.
I need to make is shorted because when user re-login into app i got this string back and put into Image source, i render this image in screen which i open with modal presentation from bottom-to-top and i'm getting small throttling when open this screen
How to improve performance of my modal screen?

Don't use base64. Use the actual image contents (with the proper mime type) to send the data.
Bonus: Use gzip to further reduce the size of the payload before sending the contents on the wire. (note: you can also use this if you still want to use base64. the size of the payload will be reduced). Remember to set the HTTP headers accordingly.
Alternative: Have a maximum image size (choose one maximum dimension and resize the other dimension based on the first one to keep the aspect ratio) and resize it before sending it on the wire (might incur some extensive computing power, depending on how big the image is and how often you need to do this).
Alternative 2 (I don't like this one personally): Split the base64 image into multiple parts, and send multiple calls... Since it's a string, set a maximum size of X bytes and fire sequential messages on the API: { part: 1, total_parts: 8, data: "some part of the base64 code to be concatenated on the server"}.
